# GZIP Deflate with CURL(PHP) web service issue

Tags: xml, web-services, post, curl

I am having a problem. It deals with a web service using POST method with cURL. 
I am trying to compress the request with GZIP,DEFLATE. 
If you look on line three this is how it was done.

```
     $x = curl_init("http://url");
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  **curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate');** 
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $inputdata);
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $data = curl_exec($x);
```

I get a response HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 22 Oct 2012 16:19:23 GMT Server: Resin/1.11.14 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: **gzip** Content-Length: 2088

However, The web service provider says that it is not compressed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put in the full header when setting [CURLOPT_ENCODING](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), just set it to an empty string, and curl will put in the supported encodings.

```
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '')
```

Comment: Thanks ninaj, It seems about right based on the documentation. I am going to implement it the way you show and let you know the results. Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm, better than defining the encode type, just keep it blank, it seems more efficent